# Retrieving attributes from a foreign key related model's to another foreign key related field model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have three models which are related to each other in different relations. First, the Parent model, which is related to the student using a foreign key relation also the student model is related to the attendance model using a foreign key relation. I want to create a serializer where I can retrieve the attendance of each parent's child separately. How can this be done?

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, default=None)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.firstName + ' ' + self.user.lastName

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, default=None)
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='students')
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    @property
    def remarks(self):
        return self.remark_set.all()

    @property
    def marks(self):
        return self.marks_set.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.firstName + ' ' + self.user.lastName

class Attendance(models.Model):
    Subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    class_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student_today', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    present = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.class_date) + '_' + str(self.student.user.username) + '_' + str(self.Subject.name)
```

**serilaizers.py**

```
class BasicUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('firstName', 'lastName')


class BasicStudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('batch', 'age')


class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = BasicUserSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    child = BasicStudentSerializer(read_only=True,  many= False)

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
class ParentView( mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ParentSerializer
```

Comment: `the Parent model, which is related to the student using one to one relation` - it is not. It is `Parent M:1 Student`. And this relation does not make much sense: a student can _rarely_ have more than 2 parents whereas some parents may have a dozen of children.

Comment: Sorry for the typo fixing it

Comment: According to your model defination, one parent can't have more than one student. You may want to put `parent` as foreign key in your `Student` table. Also, after doing that please read about serializer Method field, which will fulfill your need.

Comment: `each parent's child` you don't have "parents children" in your data model. You have "child's parents" - you've defined reversed relation. A parent in your model can be related to only one child (student).

Comment: Isn't there any other way to retrieve the attendance of a given child, instead of updating the models?

Comment: These things are not related. Once again, there are no **parents CHILDREN** possible in your data model - it is not what you think/say.